# Volkswagen Golf 2005 - Fueltank cap does not open

Tags: fuel-tank, golf, old-cars

I have a problem with my golf 5, earlier someone has tried to steal gas from my tank, but failed this, when I try to open my fueltank cap from the inside (button on the driver door) i can hear the familiar sound for opening the cap, but nothing happens, i heard about there can be a spring or something that has falled out of position, my question is how do I get it in place again ?

Here is a picture of the latch:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually what happens is that the spring falls out.  I've had this happen in both my cars.  I've been able to open them by sticking my keys in the top opening and popping the open lever real quick.  Then, retrive keys from ground and fill up car (until a new spring can be purchased and installed).  :-)

I hope that's all it is, but it's certainly possible that more damage was done during the theft attempt.

Answer (score 0):

If you press the release button, can someone else open the flap? That will confirm that it is the spring and not the release mechanism or hinge. (they may need to use a small screwdriver or similar to get leverage, but usually you can press in on the hinge side of the flap enough to get a finger around the other end)

I think the spring on these types of flaps is usually wrapped around the hinge, so you should be able to see it once you've got the flap open...

Comment: I can open the cap outside with or withhout pushing the button, it does not lock in place, and pushing the button while someone is looking, I can see the black plastic thing goes up and down which probably should push the lock into place, maybe a picture of a good  cap would tell me if the cap is bend or not bend in the correct way?

Comment: here is a picture about the fuel cap now

http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/1295/img444h.jpg

Comment: That latch looks fairly normal. There should also be a spring, probably on the other side of the flap by the hinge.

Comment: seems there is nothing else to do than send the car to service to have it repaired theere, it's to broken to be fixed by myself I guess..